# macOS Excel 16 doesn't support DateTime x-axis for XY-Scatter charts

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I recently realized that Excel for Mac doesn't support DateTime x-axis for XY-Scatter charts. I do remember it previously does.

Below is the screenshot to illustrate this issue

[image]

1. It seems Excel doesn't honor the raw/literal value of the first column, it just assume the x-axis starts with 0 and the maximum value is 30,000
2. There is no way to customize it in the panel of (Format Axis->Axis Options->Number)
3. I tried to set the format of the first column to be either Date/Time/General/Text/Custom, none of it works

I've installed version 16.16.7 of Microsoft@Excel for Mac

Comment: Date/times are just numbers.  It should work, but you need to format the axis values as dates and probably want to manually set a minimum value.  I'm guessing that your data is not being plotted as an XY chart.  Do you have 20-some thousand records?  It looks like it's just stacking them as category data and the X values probably just reflect the sequence number of the value.

Comment: I convert the time to a floating point number and then make earliest time 0 and go from there. Then the scatter plot should work fine.

Comment: @fixer1234 Your guess is what i thought as well, however, there is no way to format the axis as dates. It seems that the chart is not an XY chart, the X axis is just a sequence starting from 0. Maybe it's why there is no proper UI to format as dates because it is not. But why is it working like that?  The first column is a date/time column without a doubt.

Comment: @jmh I am not sure how you do the conversion, but it makes the charting more complicated. To be honest, i indeed think my requirement is quite common, however, it looks like Excel has other thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it work as my expectation. Below is the key point. When I import the data into the worksheet. Format the date/time column with a **Custom** format and make sure the expressions looks like **yyyy/m/d h:mm:ss**. Btw, i am not able to find the format to extract milliseconds.

Then draw a XY scatter chart without no special extra settings. [image]